# What was the First Science Fiction Film?

Tags: movie, history-of, science-fiction-genre

Is Georges Méliès' film [*A Trip to the Moon*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FrdVdKlxUk) (1902) the first science fiction film ever made?  Or are there any SF films before it?  I've searched and researched, on and off since I first saw it in a college film class, but have never found one that was earlier.  Are there any that predate it?

Comment: Wikipedia lists two, though the first may be a bit dubious: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science-fiction_films_before_1920

Comment: Readers that like this question may also like: [What is the earliest work considered to be Science Fiction?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46747/10622)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first sci-fi short movie made as sci-fi is clearly *A Trip to the Moon*.
There are two earlier pieces that have sci-fi elements in them:

- *La Charcuterie mécanique* from 1895 - a mechanical butcher.
- *The Clown and the Automaton* from 1897 - a circus performer producing an automaton that grew in size.

But you are asking about sci-fi movies, and *A Trip to the Moon* is the first short movie ever using this theme all the way through.

Wikipedia references:

- *[A Trip to the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Trip_to_the_Moon)* (1902)
- *[Gugusse and the Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugusse_and_the_Automaton)* (1897)
- *[La Charcuterie mécanique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Charcuterie_m%C3%A9canique)* (1895)
- [List of science fiction films before 1920](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_films_before_1920)

Comment: How can you say, "clearly?"  While you do have Wikipedia links, that is not considered the most authoritative source in the world.  Proving something doesn't exist is much harder than proving something does exist.

Comment: @TangoOversway Clearly, "clearly" in this context means that *according to the sources* there's no dispute of which is the first scifi movie. In other terms, the question is such that the answer *could* be difficult to decide on (e.g. does X constitute as scifi and so on), but it happens there si no such difficulties. Thus, clearly. Leave your personal mistrust of wikipedia out of it, please.

Comment: Based on descriptions, the two earlier works seem less like sci-fi works and more like short vignettes on sci-fi themes, where "A Trip to the Moon"  tells an adventure story.