# Does "Little Mimzy Wells" by Markiv Inias really exist?

Tags: alice-in-wonderland

In this question, "[Was there a literary inspiration for Lewis Carroll's *Alice in Wonderland*?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122718/was-there-a-literary-inspiration-for-lewis-carrolls-alice-in-wonderland)”, the questioner quotes a Wikipedia listing of some literary works inspired by Lewis Carroll's story, including:

> Little Mimzy Wells by Markiv Inias is influenced heavily by Carroll's
> works, and draws liberally from the themes present in said novels.

My searches on google for a work with this title have come up blank - the only results just repeat the above text verbatim. Markiv Inias also seems to be unknown to [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/). Is this a real work, or is it just some strange phantom?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this individual and this work don't exist. That's not to say that it might not turn out to be a typo in both the title and the author name.

Comment: I note that the Wikipedia page cited in that question no longer refers to *Little Mimzy Wells*, or two of the other works mentioned in the quote.

Comment: @F1Krazy other wiki pages still do though, such as https://manga.fandom.com/wiki/Works_based_on_Alice_in_Wonderland

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be made up of whole cloth.

The closest (single) [match to "Inias"](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=au%3AInias) in [Worldcat](https://www.worldcat.org/) is "Eneas Lope" who is listed for a single book in Persian.  [Searching for "Markiv"](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=au%3AMarkiv) turns up a number of possibilities as a *last* name, the closest of which appears to be "Ivan Markiv," author of a 1936 collection of folktales, if online translators aren't deceiving me too much.

There's not much more luck on the side of the title either; searching for ["Mimzy" in the title](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3Amimzy) yields a few pages of results, almost all of which are various editions and translations of Kuttner's collection [*The Last Mimzy: Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?89406); correcting the spelling and [searching for "mimsy"](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3Amimsy) still gives us under a hundred hits, most of which are collections and anthologies containing "[Mimsy Were the Borogroves](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46702)" after which the aforementioned collection is titled.

Notably "Wells" never turns up in any connection to "Mimsy," unlike "Mimsy Pocket" (character) or "Mimsy Farmer" (actor).

Comment: In the interests of completeness, I do have to note that there are a number of people named [Vikram Saini](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=au%3A%22Vikram+saini%22&qt=results_page) though again there aren't any publications that are at all close.

Comment: _The Last Mimzy: Stories_ is a tie in to _[The Last Mimzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Mimzy)_ - still don't see any typo-based similarities with a quick skim

Comment: That seems quite convincing @DavidW How strange, I wonder if it is some kind of plagiarism detector, like the fake roads you get in some street maps.