# What is the oldest science fiction story?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

What is the oldest science fiction story? It doesn't need to be set in the future, it could also be set in the past or a combination of the two. Plese include the author, thanks!

Comment: Closely related to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142142/were-there-science-fiction-stories-written-during-the-middle-ages and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93537/what-was-the-first-sci-fi-work-to-feature-a-spaceship. You may want to clearly define what you  consider qualifies as science fiction.

Comment: @Jack No, that question was about science fiction stories in the Middle Ages, and the oldest science fiction story seems to be [Lucian's "True History"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_History) from *before* the Middle Ages. Which someone posted, wrongly, as an answer to that other question.

Comment: @user14111 I never said they were duplicates, just related, anyone who finds this question interesting is probably also going to be interested in those.

Comment: Also related: [Who was the earliest female science fiction writer?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121351)

Comment: Agreed, defining what you mean by science fiction is probably important for this question. Strictly speaking, such assumptions come into play whenever people use the [tag:science-fiction-genre] tag, but they’re probably particularly important here. You may not consider the Epic of Gilgamesh to be sci-fi, for example.

Comment: I knew there was a duplicate *somewhere*.

Answer (score 2):

The [Epic of Gilgamesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh), author unknown, date circa 2,100 BC. It's science fiction, because it's about how the world was believed to be at the time it was written, although the same story written today would be fantasy.

Comment: So what makes it science fiction? (I haven't read it.) "Because it's about how the world was believed to be at the time" isn't enough of a reason; you could say the same about *Pride and Prejudice*.

Comment: If anything it's a superhero fantasy story. There's very little technology.